# Flutter: Instances Data get Lost with Provider when I pass to another screen

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I am trying to pass all my listing instances from my Listing Provider class to my homes_creen but the data gets lost along the way. How can I solve this?

This is my **ListingProvider** class, the one I use to make the call to my MongoDB database.

```dart
class ListingProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  var url = Uri.parse('${Constants.apiUrl}listings/');

  List<Listing> onDisplayListing = [];

  ListingProvider() {
    print("Listing Provider inicializado");
    //this.getListing();
  }

  getListing(Token token) async {
    var response = await http.get(
      url,
      headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/json',
        'accept': 'application/json',
        'authorization': "Bearer ${token.token}"
      },
    );

    final nowListingResponse = ListingResponse.fromJson(response.body);

    onDisplayListing = nowListingResponse.results;

    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

When using the vscode debugger, I notice that my :

```dart
onDisplayListing = nowListingResponse.results
```

saves instances of my database data like this:

- [0] listing [1] listing [2] listing [3] listing

So far so good. When I try to consume those instances in my home_screen, my:

```dart
listingProvider.onDisplayListing
```

does not have these instances.

my home_screen

```dart
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final Token token;
  const HomePage({required this.token, Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    ListingProvider().getListing(widget.token);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    final listingProvider = Provider.of<ListingProvider>(
      context,
    );


//when I try to print here my instances, they are empty. Why?
    print(listingProvider.onDisplayListing);


    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Find Shipments"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Text("Hola ${widget.token.user.name}!"),
      ),
      drawer: Drawer(
        child: ListView(
          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          children: [
            MyHeaderDrawer(
              token: widget.token,
            ),
            myDrawerListOption(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

If you need to know anything else, let me know.

Thanks!!!

Comment: Perhaps your data output is wrong. Read this. [Read this example](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple) You need use Consumer<HomePage>

Answer (score 0):

In your

```
@override
initState() {
    super.initState();
    ListingProvider().getListing(widget.token);
 }
```

you create a new Provider instance, while in your build() function you're retrieving the provider using `Provider.of()`. So in fact you're working with different provider instances.

Secondly, you need to notify your screen, when provider has finished loading the content. You can either work with a `Consumer` here, or you can use a `FutureBuilder` for fetching the `getListing()`, depending on your needs.

When doing with FutureBuilder, you might change to that in your Provider:

```
Future<List<Listing>> getListing(Token token) async {
  var response = await http.get(
    url,
    headers: {
      'content-type': 'application/json',
      'accept': 'application/json',
      'authorization': "Bearer ${token.token}"
    },
  );

  final nowListingResponse = ListingResponse.fromJson(response.body);
  return nowListingResponse.results;
}
```

Which could be consumed in your screen like that:

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    final listingProvider = Provider.of<ListingProvider>(
      context,
    );

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Find Shipments"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Text("Hola ${widget.token.user.name}!"),
      ),
      drawer: Drawer(
        child: ListView(
          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          children: [
            MyHeaderDrawer(
              token: widget.token,
            ),
            FutureBuilder<List<Account>>(
              future: listingProvider.getListing(),
              builder: (context, listSnapshot) {
                 if (listSnapshot.hasError) {
                    // Handle error case);
                 } else if (listSnapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                   return myDrawerListOption(listSnapshot.data);
                 } else {
                      // Handle loading
                 }                     
              }),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Something like that. The code probably has some syntax issue, since I couldn't test it.